# The function doesn't respond to the counter in while-loop

Tags: c#, function, while-loop

So i made a `while` loop with 12 grades to be reached. The counter starts at 0. In the `Main()` method i call the function `gradeFunction()` but after it is executed it doesn't doesn't make any change to the counter.

```
Program p = new Program();
string name = Console.ReadLine();
int gradesPassed = 12;
int currentGrade = 0;
double totalSumOfGrades = 0;
while(currentGrade <= gradesPassed)
{
    double finalGrade = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    p.gradeFunction(finalGrade, totalSumOfGrades,     currentGrade);
}
```

The called function:

```
public void gradeFunction(double finalGrade, double totalSumOfGrades, int currentGrade)
{
    if(finalGrade >= 4.00)
    {
       totalSumOfGrades += finalGrade;
       currentGrade++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass-By-Value. The `currentGrade` inside `gradeFunction` is _not_ the same as in the caller. It's a copy of the value. Changing it will not change the original. Either use `out` or a return value.

Comment: look up passing arguments by reference (by ref) or by value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Comment: What @Fildor said. As a learning reference: https://www.mathwarehouse.com/programming/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-visual-explanation.php

Comment: Do you really need a method for this task?

Comment: I just want to figure out how it works for this homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Jeremy said, try the following:

```
Program p = new Program();
string name = Console.ReadLine();
int gradesPassed = 12;
int currentGrade = 0;
double totalSumOfGrades = 0;
while (currentGrade <= gradesPassed)
{
    double finalGrade = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    gradeFunction(finalGrade, ref totalSumOfGrades, ref currentGrade);
}
```

```
public static void gradeFunction(double finalGrade, ref double totalSumOfGrades, ref int currentGrade)
        {
            if (finalGrade >= 4.00)
            {
                totalSumOfGrades += finalGrade;
                currentGrade++;
            }

        }
```

I have added the ref keywords for `currentGrade` and `totalSumOfGrades` on both the call and the declaration so that the variables are updated properly which I believe is the most impact-free way to get the code working.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to understand it, so why you don't explain what you have changed to make it working?

Comment: Ah sorry, I have added the `ref` keywords for `currentGrade` and `totalSumOfGrades` on both the call and the declaration so that the variables are updated properly which I believe is the most impact-free way to get the code working

Comment: Yes i just got the way it works but it also requires ref keyword in front of finalGrade. Thanks

Comment: If your assigning a new value to the original `finalGrade` then yes, however if your just passing the value which I think your current code is doing as it regens the value on each iteration of the loop, it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Yes it turns out that is not necessary

Comment: While this works, using `ref` smells bad and there is a much simpler alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The code,

```
    Console.ReadLine();
    double totalSumOfGrades = 0;

    for(var currentGrade = 0; currentGrade <= 12; currentGrade++)
    {
        var finalGrade = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (finalGrade >= 4.00)
        {
            totalSumOfGrades += finalGrade;
        }
    }
```

would be simpler and more direct.